# Why doe it use limsup?(Real analysis by Folland)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

1. In the proof of the theorem, it defines 
   $$F_{k}=\{x \in A :\limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda(B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac{1}{k} \}$$ and it proves that $m(F_{k})=0$.
   Why did not it define $F_{k}$ as follows:
   $$F_{k}=\{x \in A :\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda(B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac{1}{k} \}$$
2. In theorem 3.20 after reaching to this point that
   $$\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{m(B(r,x))}|f(y)-f(x)|dy \le\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{m(B(r,x))}|f(y)-c|+\epsilon$$
   then it uses limsup as follows:
   $$\limsup_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{m(B(r,x))}|f(y)-f(x)|dy \le|f(x)-c|+\epsilon$$
   why did not it use lim as follows:
   $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{m(B(r,x))}|f(y)-f(x)|dy \le\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{m(B(r,x))}|f(y)-c|+\epsilon=|f(x)-c|+\epsilon$$

Comment: I think the reason is, that for not all $r$ and measure on balls, the limit exists. The existence of limsup is also questionable. However you can always it define to infinity when necessary. (So depending on measures choice, the limit may not exist.)  But if ask me to give an example, i'll get stuck.

Comment: The limit may not exist, while the limit supremum will always exist (as an extended real number, i.e. it could be infinite).

Comment: By the way, who is “it”? It's quite meaningless to refer to “theorem 3.20” without saying what text you are talking about.

Comment: I am reading real analysis by Folland

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I just wanted to show my proof.

For each $c\in \mathbb{C}$ we can apply Theorem 3.18 to $g_c(x) = |f(x) - c|$ and see that outside a set $E_c$ with $m(E_c) = 0$ we have $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y) - c| dy = |f(x) - c|$$
Let $D$ be a countable dense subset in $\mathbb{C}$ and $E = \bigcup_{c\in D}E_c$ so $m(E) = 0$. Now if $x\notin E$ then given $\epsilon >0$, choose a $c\in D$ with $|f(x) - c| < \epsilon/2$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x)}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y) - f(x)|dy &\leq \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x)}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y) - c| + |c - f(x)|dy\\
&= \left(\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x)}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y) - c|dy\right) + |f(x) - c|\\
&= |f(x) - c| + |f(x) - c|\\
&< \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2\\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
(We need $D$ to be countable in order that we can ensure that  $E = \bigcup_{c\in D}E_c$ is a countable union of null sets and so it is a null set. We need $D$ to be dense to be able to use it to estimate  $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B(r,x)}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y) - f(x)|dy$.)